# Why are sets bigger than lists in python?

Tags: python, list, set

Why is the size of sets in Python noticeably larger than that of lists with same elements?

```
a = set(range(10000))
b = list(range(10000))
print('set size = ', a.__sizeof__())
print('list size = ', b.__sizeof__())
```

output:

```
set size = 524488
list size = 90088
```

Comment: Why does `9999 in a` run much faster than `9999 in b`?

Comment: The python list is implemented like a dynamic array, frankly most data structures (except tuples) would be more memory consuming.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `set` uses more memory than the `list` as it stores a table of hashes of all the elements so it can quickly detect duplicate entries and so on.  This is why every set member must [be `hashable`](http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-hashable).